# Retain Selected Value of dynamically bound dropdownlist after postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a dropdownlist which I declare on the aspx markup like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="State" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then I bind it on page load like so :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BindDropdowns();
    }
private void BindDropdowns()
    {
        State.DataSource = DataAccess.GetStates();
        State.DataValueField = "FieldId";
        State.DataTextField = "FieldName";
        State.DataBind();
    }
```

The selected value is not retained after postback, I also cannot fire the selectedindexchangedevent. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please change your code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostback)
       BindDropdowns();
}
```

This means that your dropdown control is only bound once on first pageload

Comment: Well, when I do that, the dropdownlist loses its binding after the postback, I know - it's a double edged sword... do you have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: @user560498: It shouldn't lose it's binding. If it is you're doing something wrong. There's nothing dynamic about this; it's standard databinding.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought, there's probably something else that is wrong with my page, thanks for this ....

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `AutoPostBack="true"`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="State" AutoPostBack="true" 
 runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And also state that the witch event handler like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="State" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="State_SelectedIndexChanged" 
runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in code. Bind just when not post back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostback)
       BindDropdowns();
}

protected void State_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
    var somevalue= State.SelectedValue;  
}
```